# Convert Raw Partially Structured Text into CSV or Tab Delimited Document or XML

Tags: csv

I am helping a non-profit organization organize their existing data into a database. The data includes about 200 records. They have been using a simple word document. I am starting the work of structuring the raw data so I can enter it in the database. I copied the data into Textpad and it did so nicely. That said the data is structured but is not a perfect match. For example some organizations have a website, some don't etc. Here is a sample of some information indicative of the remaining data:

[image]

I have an ERD created, it has gone through a number of revisions and was given the green light by my mentor. At this point I am at the ETL(Extract, transform, load) Process

1. Clean up the remaining partially structured but messy data.
2. Put it into an Excel readable doc type, and be arranged into the applicable tables
3. Create a data input SQL script.
4. Run the script.

I have done this already with some of the other data and it worked perfectly.

The cleaning up and putting it into Excel (CSV or Tab Delimited) is where I need the guidance. Or is it better to convert it to XML? If I manually go through the text file to ensure all the headers(for lack of a better word) match like this:

[image]

Is there a way to transfer it?

I have researched this, and I was surprised I could not find any good information. [Updated] I just found the actual term, ETL Process. If I have to just start retyping and/or cut and pasting just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two "records" are significantly different. For example some contacts have multiple phone numbers and others have only one. Additionally, the number of contacts may vary. It seems to lend itself to a relational database schema with multiple tables. However, you're going to have a hard time automating the process of populating multiple relational tables based on the data layout. How much data are you dealing with? If it's not an enormous amount, you may be better off doing this sort of half-manually, reformatting parts of your Textpad doc into INSERT statements (using lots of regular expression search and replaces), and taking some time running the queries.

If it's a truly large amount of data, then you might want to write a little program in the language of your choice to parse the file and create an output file containing the appropriate insert statements to populate all the data tables.

For a robust relational database, you'd want a database schema that includes at a minimum, the following tables:

```
Categories (map category names to IDs)
Types (map Group Types to IDs)
Organizations (including category and group type ID, name, addr, objs, activities, meetings, website, email, and an organization ID)
Contacts (one to many referencing org ID, including contact name and a contact ID)
Phone (one to many referencing contact ID, including phone type and phone number)
```

You could get away without the Types and Categories tables, but they may prove useful depending on the volume of data and how they plan to query on it in the future (e.g. if at some point they will want to find all organizations in a particular category of a particular group type, and there are at least thousands of organizations, then the extra tables will prove worthwhile).

Since the contact/phone information appears to be so flexible, you're better off putting it into separate tables -- otherwise you'd have to include columns in the main organization table for contactN/phoneN/phoneTypeN for the maximum number of possible contact/phones, and that would also create a limit on how many contact/phone associations could be made.

You had also better make sure that none of the records require multiple entries for any of the other fields (MEETINGS, EMAIL, ...). If that is a possibility, then you again need to make a choice of whether to add additional relational tables, or add multiple fields for the max possible to the organization table.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for the help and the effort but I am past this. So your first observation is the problem. I am down in the trenches preparing the raw data. I may have to edit my question. The ERD is complete and reviewed by my mentor. It is flexible enough to deal with data. The data needs to be mapped to corresponding field in the applicable table.

Comment: You could use my advice about writing a simple parsing program in the language of your choice that would read the input file (as you specified) and then generate a file with a series of INSERT statements corresponding to the parse. I would estimate that it would take me about an hour to write a Java program to do this.

Comment: Jeremy, that does have me thinking. And that would be something I would love to code! So I would obviously have to go through the text file and ensure all the subject headers matched? I am pretty certain that will be a 'yes', but I cannot imagine I am the first person to have this issue and someone has not solved it/ or made it easier already. Thanks for sticking around.

Comment: What you can do is in your code, look at each entity -- if it doesn't have a field you expect, log it somewhere (even the console), if it has a differently-named field, log that as well. So then you can go back and handle the exceptions. It does seem like a pretty cool little coding project. Enjoy. P.S. on stackoverflow if you appreciate someone's help, you should give them an upvote by clicking on the ^ next to the answer, you can also "accept" the answer (only one answer per question) by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Actually, after more thought, organizations that don't match your expectations (like misnamed headers and such) should be written in their entirety to an exceptions file (and not to the INSERT query file). This will make it super easy to handle the exceptions afterward -- just edit the exceptions file to match what your program expects and then run your program on the exceptions file.

Comment: Jeremy, I'm still here. I rolled up the sleeves and started cleaning up the data, it was a long night. I am still a junior so I cannot ^. In the same way I cannot insert actual images into questions yet. So I am working on this again today, let me try and absorb what you have said. And trust me I appreciate the help.